# Error preg_replace remove all div inside content

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$content = '<div class="block_thumb_slide_show"><img alt="smartphone" class="aligncenter size-full">Test abc<p> <strong>Màn hình 3D</strong></p></div>';
$content = preg_replace('#<div.*?>(.*?)</div>#i', '<p>\1</p>', $content);
echo $content;
```

Result can't replace div to p. How to fix it

```
<p><img alt="smartphone" class="aligncenter size-full">Test abc<p> <strong>Màn hình 3D</strong></p></p>
```

Comment: Use `preg_replace("/(</?)div/", "$1p", $content)`

Comment: What is the expected return?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace div with p why don't try using:

```
str_replace("div","p", $your_html);
```

Comment: Using `str_replace` in this case isn't right because it replace also string in tags

Comment: And if he uses <div> to <p> ?

Comment: If div has attribute `<div class...>` doesn't work. Also for closing tag `</div>`

Comment: true :D I failed :D

Comment: Maybe `str_replace("<div", "<p", str_replace("</div", "</p", $content))` work

Comment: What if text has html as text or something like a<div as text :D

Comment: Your right but if you want to use `str_replace` `<div` is better that `div`

Comment: True :D Or extract text from html and replace that text with '' and then change div with p :D